# c++ no matching function for call to: passing iterators?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I've encountered a strange problem in my C++ Code.
I've defined a TemplateClass called

```
StateTemplate<T>
```

Furthermore I defined

```
typedef StateTemplate<double> StateDouble.
```

Then I defined a friend function

```
template<class S>
friend S partialEntangledScalarProduct(
    const typename std::vector<StateTemplate<T> >::const_iterator s1,
    const typename std::vector<StateTemplate<T> >::const_iterator s2,
    const typename std::vector<StateTemplate<T> >::const_iterator sSub1,
    const typename std::vector<StateTemplate<T> >::const_iterator sSub2,
    vector<unsigned int> const &pos,
    vector<unsigned int> const &posNot);
```

If I now make

```
std::vector<StateDouble>::const_iterator s1;
std::vector<StateDouble>::const_iterator s2;
std::vector<StateDouble>::const_iterator sSub1;
std::vector<StateDouble>::const_iterator sSub2;

vector<unsigned int> vui;

Doub test=partialEntangledScalarProduct(s1,s2,sSub1,sSub2,vui,vui);
```

I get the following Error:

```
no matching function for call to 
    'partialEntangledScalarProduct(
         __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<
             const StateTemplate<double>*,
             std::vector<
                 StateTemplate<double>,
                 std::allocator<StateTemplate<double> > > >&,
         __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<
             const StateTemplate<double>*,
             std::vector<
                 StateTemplate<double>,
                 std::allocator<StateTemplate<double> > > >&,
         __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<
             const StateTemplate<double>*,
             std::vector<
                 StateTemplate<double>,
                 std::allocator<StateTemplate<double> > > >&,
         __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<
             const StateTemplate<double>*,
             std::vector<
                 StateTemplate<double>,
                 std::allocator<StateTemplate<double> > > >&,
         const std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >&,
         std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >&)'
```

I've tried for hours to find the problem, but it seems that I overlook something.
Maybe someone could help me?

best regards
Dominik

p.s.: if you need more information about my code, just let me know. At the moment I just wanted to give you the important parts.

Here is a small example with the same error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class StateTemplate{
    template<class S>
    friend S testFunction(
        const typename std::vector<StateTemplate<S> >::const_iterator s1);
public:
StateTemplate();
};

template<class T>
StateTemplate<T>::StateTemplate(){}

template<class T>
T testFunction(
        const typename std::vector<StateTemplate<T> >::const_iterator s1)
{
    return T(1);
}

int main(){
    std::vector<double>::const_iterator s1;
    double s=testFunction<double>(s1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Minimal**, self-contained, compilable example please... If we need to scroll 10 screens horizontally to see the code, something is wrong.

Comment: What is `T` in the friend function definition? Is it meant to be `S`? Can you provide a complete (but minimal) example of just the behaviour that you do not understand?

Comment: Sorry. Below you find a simple example with the same error.

Comment: @Dominik: I've uploaded your example to liveworkspace -- [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/e2d73f298594725d7984970bad490493). The problem in your example is a type mismatch between `std::vector<StateTemplate<T> >::const_iterator` (in the testFunction parameter) and `std::vector<double>::const_iterator` (passed to testFunction from `main`).

Comment: Thanks. I'm new at stackoverflow and I don't know how to post correctly. I've edited the code into my first post. But I'm very grateful for your help :)

Comment: @Mankarse: Yeah. That was a type in the small example. Then the small example compiles :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you presented the declaration of `partialEntangledScalarProduct` correctly, the template parameter `S` isn't used anywhere in the function parameter list. Therefore, the compiler would never deduce it and you have to provide it explicitly.

```
partialEntangledScalarProduct<SomeClass>(s1,s2,sSub1,sSub2,vui,vui);
```

`SomeClass` is just an example, the exact name is unclear unless you provide more details.

Comment: Wow! That was the error! Seems to be a problem with typename.

Answer (score 1):

*(I don't have g++ on this machine, so this is conjecture.)*

I think the issue is that the compiler can't deduce `S` and you're getting an unhelpful error message. Change your usage to the following:

```
double test = partialEntangledScalarProduct<double>(s1,s2,sSub1,sSub2,vui,vui);
```

As a side note, make sure your examples compile for you before you post them. I'm assuming `Doub` was supposed to be `double`?

Comment: Yeah. Thank you, too! :) I don't know whom to thank. So, thanks to everybody.